# Trying to create a measure in PowerBi

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a measure that would be something like;
If transportation is Cars and they are Toyota and Honda and Ford and if dates are between 01/01/2019 and 10/01/2019 then the total should be 54000. This is an example. I'm not sure if I need to separate the data from the master list in order to get the information I need.

Comment: Please check this post [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and review your question. Include such as what your model looks like, code you've tried etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is as simple as it sounds and you have some existing measure to give you the "total" of 54,000 (if not, use SUMX or something instead), it should be something like this:

```
Measure1 = 
CALCULATE ( 
    [total], 
    Table1[transportation] IN {"Ford", "Honda", "Toyota"}, 
    Table1[date] >= FORMAT ( "1/1/2019", "Short Date" ),
    Table1[date] <= FORMAT ( "10/1/2019", "Short Date" )
)
```